# How to stop threads in ThreadPool without using shutdown

Tags: java

I've autowired a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in my applications. And I want to reuse the pool.But now I have a taskList that I've to invoke, and I hope once there is exception in one task others will be terminate immediately.
My ThreadPoolTaskExecutor are configed like below:

```java
    @Bean(name = "reportExecutor")
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor reportExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(3000);
        executor.setKeepAliveSeconds(300);
        executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("reportExecutor-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
```

My test cannot work as what I expect. Once I invoke the excutor's shutdown method, the excutors become disabled and won't accept tasks any more.

```java
    @Resource(name = "reportExecutor")
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor;

    @GetMapping("/testExecutors")
    public void testExecutors() {
        List<FutureTask<Integer>> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
        FutureTask<Integer> task1 = new FutureTask<Integer>(() -> {
            int i = 1/0;
            return 1;
        });
        taskList.add(task1);
        executor.execute(task1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            FutureTask<Integer> task = new FutureTask<Integer>(() -> {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                return 1;
            });
            taskList.add(task);
            executor.execute(task);
        }
        for (FutureTask<Integer> task : taskList) {
            try {
                task.get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                executor.shutdown();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you calling shutdown?

Comment: I've just said that if one of these thread occurs exception, all threads' working are useless. So I want to stop these threads immediately. I only found shutdown method but it cannot satisfy my reuseable of a executor. Once I call shutdown, it no longer accept task, and I don't want to renew a ThreadPool in my system.

Comment: Calling [shutdown](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) doesn't 'terminate' the other tasks, it will prevent other tasks from starting. `shutdownNow` will cause executing tasks to be canceled. If you want to reuse the executor, don't call shutdown. You could go through the Futures and cancel them manually, you could use another object that the tasks check to see if they should run or terminate.